# Change font size for all power point slide notes

Tags: fonts, microsoft-powerpoint

I have printed out my power point slides and the default font size for the notes is too large. Is there any way to make the note's font size smaller for all slides?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you haven't selected and change the size of the fonts on the individual notes pages, go to **View | Notes Master** and change the text size on the notes placeholder on the master.

This may not change the notes text on all slides. Before printing, using **View | Notes Page**, check the notes text has changed to your desired size. Manually change any notes text that wasn't updated by the Notes Master.

Answer (score 0):

To change the font size for all PowerPoint slide notes, you can follow these steps:

Open your PowerPoint presentation.
Switch to the "Normal" view or the "Outline" view. You can do this by clicking on the corresponding option in the View tab of the PowerPoint ribbon.
In the left pane, you will see the thumbnail view of your slides and the corresponding slide notes below each slide.
Press "Ctrl" + "A" on your keyboard to select all the slide notes.
With all the slide notes selected, go to the "Home" tab in the PowerPoint ribbon.